# Xpath Google Sheets counting class icon from html

Tags: xpath, web-scraping, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Relatively new to Xpath using google sheets. I am trying to get scores from a movie website where the score is out of five stars with images used for the stars, so I need to count the class icon-star-full from the HTML below

```
<span class="rating "><i class="icon-star-full"></i> <i class="icon-star-full"></i> <i class="icon-star-full"></i> <i class="icon-star-full"></i> <i class="icon-star"></i></span>
```

In Google Sheets, the count function seems to be working fine for every class I try except for icon-star-full. For example count(//*[@class='rating']) works fine I get a count of every class named rating. However count(//*[@class='icon-star-full']) returns 0 on every page. For example, in the HTML above I should get 3 for my count but it's 0.

It there any different way I should be doing the count for icons?

Comment: what is the URL?

Comment: Sorry its https://entertainment.ie/cinema/movie-reviews/a-bump-along-the-way-417958/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
=COUNTA(IFERROR(QUERY(ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(IMPORTDATA(A1), 1000, 1), 
 "where Col1 contains 'icon-star-full'")))&"/5"
```

where **A1** is your URL

[image: 0]